# Investigate the convergence of this triginometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

investigate the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$$
All the terms of this series is bounded for sure. But couldn't move anywhere else- question mainly asks for what values of $x$ does this converge.

Comment: also, the series approaches x/n^2 as n tends to infinity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For series involving sine, the following is always useful:

$$|\sin(x)|<|x|$$

Which holds for $x\ne0$.  Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\sin(x/n^2)|<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x|}{n^2}$$

Which is the p-series and converges everywhere.

Comment: Whoops so fast! I was writing an answer.